# How to send a get to a server and wait a get in my app in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, request

I am using Zapier to search some information in google sheets. I used Webhocks to send a GET to his server with a JSON information. The response of GET is an "OK" and I can't custom this. 
So, they will execute a task, find what a I want and return a value, but the response must be a GET in my server, and I don't know how to intercept this response in my route.
I'm trying to study Rails Rack to intercept de request in my app, but I don't know how to send the response to the event that sent the first GET.

How is my middleware:

```
class DeltaLogger
    def initialize app
        @app = app
    end

    def call env
        Rails.logger.debug "#{env['QUERY_STRING']}"        
        @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)
        [@status, @headers, @response]
    end
end
```

Thanks!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s3r6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to get the value returned from Zapier, I created two routes and a global class cache.

```
class Zapier
require 'httparty'
    def initialize
        @answer = ""
        @id = 0
    end

    def request(uri, task)
        last_event = Event.last
        puts last_event.inspect
        if last_event.nil? 
            last_id = 0
        else
            last_id = last_event.event_id
        end
        event_id = last_id + 1
        Event.find_or_create_by(event_id: event_id)
        result = HTTParty.post(uri.to_str,
        :body => {id: event_id, task: task}.to_json,
        :headers => {'content-Type' => 'application/json'})
        @answer = ""
        @id = event_id
    end

    def response(event_id, value)
        if event_id != @id
            @answer = ""
        else
            @answer = value
        end       
    end

    def get_answer
        @answer
    end
end
```

And my controller:

```
class ZapierEventsController < ApplicationController
  require 'zapier_class'
  before_action :get_task, only: [:get]
  before_action :get_response, only: [:set]
  @@zapier ||= Zapier.new
  def get
    @@zapier.request('https://hooks.zapier.com',@task)
    sleep 10 #Wait for response
    @value = @@zapier.get_answer
    render json: { 'value': @value }, status: 
  end

  def set  
    @@zapier.response(@id, @value)
    render json: { 'status': 'ok' }, status: 200
  end

  def get_task
    @task = params["task"]
  end
  def get_response
    @id = Integer(params["id"])
    @value = params["value"]
  end
end
```

Now i have to make a Task Mananger